# Ionic Capacitor iOS Firebase App Fails To Start

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, capacitor

My Ionic Capacitor App fails to start on iOS (White screen)

Only clue in the console is this -

[error] - ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: This operation is not supported in the environment this application is running on. "location.protocol" must be http, https or chrome-extension and web storage must be enabled.

Working fine on Android - I'm not using social sign-ins (use email)

Really not sure on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this to fix

```
npm i @angular/fire
npm update @angular/cli @angular/core
```

Weird that Android worked fine on the same version of @angular/fire